# How to index an &str and push the chosen element to String?

Tags: rust

To complete a task on codewars, i have to be able to push one element of str to String.
I have tried this:

```
str_to.push_str(from_utf8(&s.as_bytes([count_alpha_all..count_alpha_all)))
```

(countalpha is an integer)

But there is an error:

```
str_to.push_str(from_utf8(&s.as_bytes([count_alpha_all..count_alpha_all]));
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&str`, found enum `Result`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&str`
                   found enum `Result<&str, Utf8Error>`
```

How to fix that?

Comment: `str_to += &s[count_alpha_all - 1..count_alpha_all];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String::push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) over a slice of the `str`:

```rust
let s = "Foo Bar";
let mut res = String::new();
res.push_str(&s[4..]);
```

Prints out: `Bar`

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ef3e3bbc629d34a07755e52bb2be43a)

Answer (score 0):

There error is straight forward `from_utf8` returns `Result<String, FromUtf8Error>`. So you simply have to do this.

```
str_to.push_str(from_utf8(&s.as_bytes([count_alpha_all..count_alpha_all)).unwrap());
```

If `from_utf8` will fail program will panic.